# A problem when I try Solr in php

Tags: php, solr

I have a problem when I run an example in PHP, the code is below:

```
<?php
  require_once( 'SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php' );

  // 
  // 
  // Try to connect to the named server, port, and url
  // 
  $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr/' );

  if ( ! $solr->ping() ) {
    echo 'Solr service not responding.';
    exit;
  }

  //
  //
  // Create two documents to represent two auto parts.
  // In practice, documents would likely be assembled from a 
  //   database query. 
  //
  $parts = array(
    'spark_plug' => array(
      'partno' => 1,
      'name' => 'Spark plug',
      'model' => array( 'Boxster', '924' ),
      'year' => array( 1999, 2000 ),
      'price' => 25.00,
      'inStock' => true,
    ),
    'windshield' => array(
      'partno' => 2,
      'name' => 'Windshield',
      'model' => '911',
      'year' => array( 1999, 2000 ),
      'price' => 15.00,
      'inStock' => false,
    )
  );

  $documents = array();

  foreach ( $parts as $item => $fields ) {
    $part = new Apache_Solr_Document();

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $value ) {
      if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach ( $value as $datum ) {
          $part->setMultiValue( $key, $datum );
        }
      }
      else {
        $part->$key = $value;
      }
    }

    $documents[] = $part;
  }

  //
  //
  // Load the documents into the index
  // 
  try {
    $solr->addDocuments( $documents );
    $solr->commit();
    $solr->optimize();
  }
  catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  //
  // 
  // Run some queries. Provide the raw path, a starting offset
  //   for result documents, and the maximum number of result
  //   documents to return. You can also use a fourth parameter
  //   to control how results are sorted and highlighted, 
  //   among other options.
  //
  $offset = 0;
  $limit = 10;

  $queries = array(
    'partno: 1 OR partno: 2',
    'model: Boxster',
    'name: plug'
  );

  foreach ( $queries as $query ) {
    $response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit );

    if ( $response->getHttpStatus() == 200 ) { 
      // print_r( $response->getRawResponse() );

      if ( $response->response->numFound > 0 ) {
        echo "$query <br />";

        foreach ( $response->response->docs as $doc ) { 
          echo "$doc->partno $doc->name <br />";
        }

        echo '<br />';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo $response->getHttpStatusMessage();
    }
  }
?>
```

But once run the following error is shown:

```
'400' Status: Bad Request
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''400' Status: Bad Request' in C:\software\study\php\xampp\xampp\htdocs\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php:338 Stack trace: #0 C:\software\study\php\xampp\xampp\htdocs\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(1170): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('http://localhos...') #1 C:\software\study\php\xampp\xampp\htdocs\solr1.php(98): Apache_Solr_Service->search('partno: 1 OR pa...', 0, 10) #2 {main} thrown in C:\software\study\php\xampp\xampp\htdocs\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php on line 338
```

What could be the problem.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely have either (a) bad query syntax, or (b) a misconfigured index.

**Checking Your Index**

Looks like you have fields for partno, model, etc. You need to make sure these are configured in your [schema.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). I might guess that you don't have them created there and so your document submission is failing, or that you have a field for model but it is not multivalued.

If its getting past document submission, then you may have a querying issue...

**Debugging a Query**

The easiest way to debug your query is to echo the query before you send it. In this case:

```
 echo $query
```

Take the output from that and hit:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=<query>
```

(where  is the query from the echo statement).

You will likely get a 400 error. My guess is you have a bad field name in there somewhere or are using invalid syntax in your query. If you can post $query it would make it easier to help with the issue.

Comment: Thanks very much! The problem is the misconfigured index, I am new to Solr.

Comment: Same here, Thanks. 
New to Solr too and it looks I'm trying to add fields that don't exist in the default "demo" index(es).

Comment: For me, it was inserting data but throwing exception at `$solr->optimize();`